# unable to download XLSX.Full.Min.JS

Tags: javascript, excel

I am using below referenced code for Export to Excel:

[How to export HTML tables to a single excel workbook with different sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368626/how-to-export-html-tables-to-a-single-excel-workbook-with-different-sheets)

To execute this code we need the JS "xlsx.full.min" as mentioned below

```
<script>
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.10.3/xlsx.full.min.js"> 
</script>
```

But I am getting a corrupt version of the js from given path and unable to find the correct format or correct version.
Please suggest the correct path where I can get the js in a right format.

Here is the Image of xlsx.full.min.js....

[image: Here is the Image of xlsx.full.min.js ...e]

Comment: <script> src="...  should be <script src="...."></script>

Comment: This is just the typo error here otherwise I have written exactly same as u suggested and able to access JS,  but my problem is that JS is being downloaded or achieved in a corrupted format(mix of english & some other language). Could u plz suggest any other path or website where I get it from in a right or working format.

Comment: Is JS at below link is Good??  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.4/xlsx.full.min.js