# Javascript code to export two html tables into two sheets in CSV file

Tags: javascript

Can someone please let me know how to export two html tables into two sheets in a single csv file using Javascript. Each sheet should contain single table. I have tried the below code , but it works for only single html table. I am trying to do it for two html tables but it displays both the tables in a single sheet. Thank you in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/gengns/j1jm2tjx/

```
 function download_csv(csv, filename) {
var csvFile;
var downloadLink;

// CSV FILE
csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

// Download link
downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

// File name
downloadLink.download = filename;

// We have to create a link to the file
downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

// Make sure that the link is not displayed
downloadLink.style.display = "none";

// Add the link to your DOM
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

// Lanzamos
downloadLink.click();
}

function export_table_to_csv(html, filename) {
var csv = [];
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
        row.push(cols[j].innerText);

    csv.push(row.join(","));        
}

// Download CSV
download_csv(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
var html = document.querySelector("table").outerHTML;
export_table_to_csv(html, "table.csv");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do this by pure js, but [sheetjs](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) can help.

I'm combined your example and this answer [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368626/how-to-export-html-tables-to-a-single-excel-workbook-with-different-sheets/50595709), hope it will help you.

```js
function download_csv(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    // CSV FILE
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // We have to create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Make sure that the link is not displayed
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to your DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Lanzamos
    downloadLink.click();
}

function s2ab(s) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0; i != s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    return buf;
}


function export_table_to_csv(index) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table");

    var rowNew = rows[index].querySelectorAll('tr');

    for (var i = 0; i < rowNew.length; i++) {
        var row = [],
            cols = rowNew[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);

        csv.push(row.join(","));

    }


    return csv.join("\n");
}

function doExcel1(fileName) {
    var csv = [];
    var blob,
        wb = { SheetNames: [], Sheets: {} };

    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('table').length; i++) {

        var sheetd = 'Sheet' + i;

        var ws1 = XLSX.read(export_table_to_csv(i), { type: "binary" }).Sheets.Sheet1;
        wb.SheetNames.push(sheetd);
        wb.Sheets[sheetd] = ws1;

    }

    blob = new Blob([s2ab(XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' }))], {
        type: "application/octet-stream"
    });

    download_csv(blob, fileName);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var html = document.querySelector("table").outerHTML;
    doExcel1('test.xlsx');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.10.3/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Country</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Geronimo</td><td>26</td><td>France</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Natalia</td><td>19</td><td>Spain</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Silvia</td><td>32</td><td>Russia</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Country</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Geronimo</td><td>26</td><td>France</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Natalia</td><td>19</td><td>Spain</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Silvia</td><td>32</td><td>Russia</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Country</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Geronimo</td><td>26</td><td>France</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Natalia</td><td>19</td><td>Spain</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Silvia</td><td>32</td><td>Russia</td></tr> 
</table>
<button>Export HTML table to CSV file</button>
```

Also see in action here:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oL72hn6c/)