# Export html tables to multiple sheets xlsx file not xls using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, excel, export-to-excel

I have requirement to export html tables on my web page to multiple sheets excel workbook with xlsx extension.

There are many threads in stackoverflow that tells way to export to xls file but i need to export to xlsx file

I need to do this using JQuery or javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you do for `.xls`? can you not pass `.xlsx` with filename?

Comment: I mean I found a solution for  .xls and using same method putting   .xlsx in filename doesn't work.

Comment: What is solution for XLS? Are you using external library? May be it is the limitation of that then?

Comment: Please consider updating your question with the actual code you tried that didn't work. without looking at the code, it's impossible to say why one is working but not the other.

Comment: I have modified the question. can someone vote this question up as I have been blocked by stackoverflow

Comment: Use sheetjs (npm xlsx), and other library for take data from html tables. Without close we can't province fixes or better opinions about

Comment: @shaik I don't know why this was downvoted. But your question is missing the code or your efforts to achieve the expected behavior. You need to post the code that is not working to your expectations, so others on SO can find where your code went wrong. Currently, this question is "discussion based". Please update the question with the code you have which is not working and what error is thrown or what's happening that you need to fix. Other than that, refer to [this post](https://datainflow.com/export-multiple-html-tables-multiple-excel-sheets-using-javascript/) and try with `xlsx`

Comment: @pirate to post my code. i have not yet started on writing code i am in search for solution so there is no question of error or what fix i want etc. the post you provided also has xls file extension in the file name and it wont work if i change that to xlsx, it still downloads in xls format only.

Comment: @shaik I've added an answer for single table. Implement your logic first for multiple sheet by using documentation or link to other answer I've added and update question with your logic. Accept the answer if it helped so others can be benefited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Without knowing your approach because the implementation hasn't been started at your end as mentioned in the comments in your question, it is hard to understand your code structure. This example only exports one table, but you should be able to dig through the libraries documentation to find out the possible ways to merge different tables in single file. Just search for multiple sheet in single file with `sheet js` or [check this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50595709/9340890). Implement your logic and if run into issues, update the question with the problem.

You can make use of the available javascript libraries to generate `xlsx` file.
You will need to add following scripts on the page. The only drawback with this approach is 4 external libraries, so only load them on a page you need.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/blob.js@1.0.1/Blob.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/file-saver@1.3.3/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

Create a table with your data

```
  <table id="tableToExport">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john@mailserver.com</td>
      <td>USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane Doe</td>
      <td>jane@mailserver.com</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Add event listener on a button or any element to trigger export.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("createXLSX");
var fileName = "test";
var fileType = "xlsx";
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
   var table = document.getElementById("tableToExport");
   var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(table, {sheet: "Sheet JS"});
   return XLSX.writeFile(wb, null || fileName + "." + (fileType || "xlsx"));
});
```

Check out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/hrdave/pen/bGwpQLx) to see the functionality.